# How do I get 'react-native-cli' to run my app in the specified hardware?

Tags: ios, react-native, webstorm

The React Native CLI will not run the specified simulator. When I enter

```
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli run-ios ‑‑simulator="iPhone X"
```

the simulator runs as expected, but insists on running in an iPhone 6, regardless of what `simulator` I specify, and if I select an additional hardware from the simulator app's menu, the one that launches does not show my project. (In fact, if I an iPhone X, it shows an app that I worked on some time ago instead.)

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the `react-native-cli`, and have no additional global `ios-sim` (though I had one once).

How do I get `react-native-cli` to run my app in the specified hardware?

---

My starting place for encountering these errors is simply (1) to install `react-native-cli`, (2) install WebStorm, (3) build a default React Native project there, and (4) run the project using the default iOS run configuration there. (WebStorm 2018.1.5; macOS 10.13.5; React Native CLI 2.0.1; Node 10.6.0)

Comment: @Li357 I'm using WebStorm and which generates the command line above and that's what I want to get working.

Comment: `react-native-cli` should pick up current running simulator and should run app there. So please try to start the desired simulator first manually and then run the command.

Comment: @bennygenel If I do that the same thing happens. Starting the simulator independently brings up the iPhone X with my old app installed. Then running the above brings up a 6 with my current app launched.

Comment: Did you try to delete the app from iPhone X and then run the command again? Seems like bundle is cached and no rebuilding. trying to delete cache might help. Also you can try to run your app from Xcode

Comment: @bennygenel Yes. Running the command above with the simulator closed launches into a 6. Running the command with the simulator open does the same. Opening an X in the simulator shows nothing installed.

Comment: can you try to run your app from Xcode with selecting the desired simulator please

Comment: @bennygenel If I build and run from Xcode, I get an X there.

Comment: Is the app starts there when you build? I'm not sure whats going on but I believe it is about [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/b99609e9d242e5aaa2b0f14c08e8805b8903bc83/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js#L159)

Comment: @bennygenel In Xcode after building I run it explicitly in a selected simulator (it doesn't start when I build).

Answer (score 4):

The CLI goes through a few simple steps which you can step through [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/edf71005b5a4d7cfb09eae14f5765d30b9c5704e/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js#L23).

The first parameter is the output of running this from the command line:
`xcrun simctl list --json devices`

A few things to check first after running the xcrun command above:

- Do you see multiple child nodes that **start with** 'iOS'? If so, you may have multiple versions of the simulators installed. The CLI will only look at the first version that it finds that starts with 'iOS'. So if there is only one simulator in that particular version, you're going to get that one all the time.
- Find the iPhone 6 simulator, does it show it's `state` as `Booted`? If so, it will take priority if a simulator name is not provided
- Is the iPhone X simulator `availability` listed as `(available)`?
- Did you reboot the computer to kill any stale simulator processes? This should also reset the `state` and `availability` statuses of the simulators

Other than that, the cli does a pretty simple check:

- If a simulator is Booted and no name is provided, start that one.
- Launch the first simulator in the list if no name match was found using the  `name` property

Comment: I have several `com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime....` nodes and one `iOS ...` node corresponding to `iOS 11.4`. All of the entries there, including a single X and a single 6 entry have `"state" : "Shutdown"` and `"availability" : "(available)"`.

Comment: When you run it with --simulater="iPhone X", then run the xcrun command again, it just shows that the 6 is running?

Comment: After trying a bunch of things (I tried so many I'm not sure what did it) I can get the app running in an X, but nothing I can do gets rid of the 6. Even if I have the simulator running with just the X open, when I run the command in the OP, a 6 gets launched and only there does the app open automatically.

Comment: That's really strange.. unfortunately, you next step is to debug the CLI. The globally installed CLI will forward commands to your local react native folder. So from your root react native project, go to ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js and add a `console.log()` to the `findMatchingSimulator()` method.. then debug from there..